# Text to speech on Quizlet.com

Tags: api, open-source, text-to-speech

How did they implement text to speech (TTS)? Is there an open, free API for TTS synthesis? I know about Google Translate, but the license is not clear to me (another issue is that they block a request if it contains a referrer). Any idea?

Answer (score 12):

Majdron,

I'm a lead developer at Quizlet. We're using a combination of our own technology and licensing/purchasing TTS software from several different companies.

There are some open source TTS engines/voices:

- http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/
- http://www.babelfish.org/tts-free.htm
- http://espeak.sourceforge.net/
- http://freetts.sourceforge.net/docs/index.php
- http://mary.dfki.de/

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

The voices sound exactly the same as http://www.neospeech.com. Also, their list of languages match exactly.

It's not free, you have to license it.

Answer (score 0):

Google has just introduced browser-based access to its speech engine through HTML5.

http://slides.html5rocks.com/#speech-input

To get this page to work, I launched the Chromium browser as follows in Ubuntu:

```
$ chromium-browser --enable-speech-input
```

I'm not sure if this works in other operating systems.

Another interesting project is WAMI from MIT:

http://wami.csail.mit.edu

Comment: This is in the voice recognition side rather than the TTS side that the OP was asking about. Quizlet is using MIT's WAMI though also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which specific engine Quizlet are using, but assuming they are using a free service then it might be TTS-API (http://tts-api.com/) which was recently featured on Hacker News.

From what I know is the only "free-to-use" TTS web-API out there. Please comment below if I'm wrong - I'd love to find similar *free* services. There are a lot of pay only services out there but very very few truly free ones.

Since finding out about TTS-API on HN I've successfully used it in a recent app project. Since the TTS is only a HTTP fetch away I was able to quickly integrate it in both the iOS and Android versions of my app. The service appears to be very quick, so no complaints so far :-)

Answer (score 0):

Nobody gave the right answer. They have their own TTS engine that is connected to a single file located at http://quizlet.com/tts/en.mp3 the file takes arguments with it so the url http://quizlet.com/tts/en.mp3?v=14&b=QXJlYSBvZiBwYXJhbGxlbG9ncmFt&s=m5dx52Q. says "Area of parallelogram" thanks the first base64 string labeled b. I have not discovered what v or s are used for but I know they are essential for making the file speak. I will do more research and get back to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

jj b is correct. The core engine of Quizlet's speech features is Neospeech, and uses Neospeech's VTML (VoiceText [TM] Markup Language) exactly, as far as I can tell.

Comment: This would have been more appropriate as a comment on jj b's existing answer (or as you can't yet comment on answers that aren't yours, a simple *upvote* would have been appropriate).